# Creating an iPhone- and iPad-compatible app with a storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, ios-universal-app

I am trying to create an iPhone and iPad compatible app. 
Is there any good tutorial and example I can follow?
Can I create one view or storyboard for each view and use it for iPhone and iPad?
If I use a storyboard, can I do something like this:
If it's iPhone, use this storyboard design, if iPad, use the other storyboard design. 
Or do I need to create a new view or storyboard for iPad and one for iPhone?
I have no clue how to start at this moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one storyboard to build an interface that is compatible with both iPad and iPhone models.

Apple is now encouraging developers to embrace Adaptive User Interfaces. As their [guide](https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/) states, "With the latest advancements with View Controllers in iOS 8 and Auto Layout in Xcode, it’s now even easier for you to adapt your user interface to context and different sized devices". In other words, you only need a single storyboard for all iOS devices, also known as a "Universal" storyboard.

This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial) should get you started with Universal Storyboards and adaptive layout.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am reading your tutorial and it's awesome!

Comment: My pleasure! Not my tutorial though---just one I found very helpful :)